# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_solution' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['share/(?P<pk>\\d+)/add_solution/$']

Tags: django

The point is, i have exercises + solutions
And when i click on execsise there is add solution button,but...
I'm getting this error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'add_solution' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['share/(?P<pk>\\d+)/add_solution/$']
```

my urls.py:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/add_solution/$', views.add_solution, name='add_solution'),
```

My view:

```
def add_solution(request, pk = None):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ShareForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Share:show_code')
    else:
        form = ShareForm()
    return render(request, 'share/add_solution.html', {'form': form})
```

my template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'Share:add_solution' pk%}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                       <button class="btn btn-success px-5">Add solution</button>
 </form>
```

If i remove (?P\d+)   from url, ir works, but i need to specify the exercise manually. But i want to get the id of exercise from url and autofill the exercise fill while adding solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Reverse for 'add_solution' with arguments '('',)'`

The `pk` variable in your template context is either the empty string `''` or not defined. It should be a number.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'Share:add_solution' pk %}">
```

Comment: as i understand, my button directly redirects to ^add_solution/$ ignoring  pk, how can i make the button to go ^pk/add_solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Either your url pattern requires the `pk` value or it doesn't. If it requires pk, then you have to provide the pk.

Comment: Oh, got you.Thank you